# Django dict expect at most 1 argument , got 3 error

Tags: django

I have a model called Picture which has 2 imagefield .One called Image and one called small . The main reason why I have 2 imagefield is because , my functions underneath my model will resize the image and save it according to their location.

My main goal is to mininimze the unwanted code because I have 2 duplicate function that  perform the same action but for different fields . Instead of having 2 function , we can create one that will be perform the same action but for different fields.

```
class Picture(models.Model):

    small = models.ImageField(upload_to="small/",blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/",blank=True)

    def save(self , force_insert=False,force_update=False):
        super (Picture,self).save(force_insert,force_update)

        pw = self.image.width
        ph = self.image.height
        mw = 500
        mh = 500

        if (pw > mw) or (ph > mh):
            filename = str(self.image.path)
            imageObj = img.open(filename)
            ratio = 1

            if ( pw > mw):
                ratio = mw / float(pw)
                pw = mw
                ph = int(math.floor(float(ph)* ratio))
            if ( ph > mh):
                ratio = ratio * ( mh /float(ph))
                ph = mh 
                pw = int(math.floor(float(ph)* ratio))

            imageObj = imageObj.resize((pw,ph),img.ANTIALIAS)
            imageObj.save(filename)

    def small(self , force_insert=False,force_update=False):
        super (Picture,self).save(force_insert,force_update)

        pw = self.small.width
        ph = self.small.height
        mw = 1500
        mh = 1500

        if (pw > mw) or (ph > mh):
            filename = str(self.small.path)
            imageObj = img.open(filename)
            ratio = 1

            if ( pw > mw):
                ratio = mw / float(pw)
                pw = mw
                ph = int(math.floor(float(ph)* ratio))
            if ( ph > mh):
                ratio = ratio * ( mh /float(ph))
                ph = mh 
                pw = int(math.floor(float(ph)* ratio))

            imageObj = imageObj.resize((pw,ph),img.ANTIALIAS)
            imageObj.save(filename)
```

What I tried to do is create  a class called Resizier with an argument of the field . So if I upload an image in the small field ,  My model will determine with an If statement if small . convert into a image variable and call Resizier class .

The problem is I get this

```
   error dict expect at most 1 argument , got 3
```

my models.py

```
from pet.fields import Resizier

class Picture(models.Model):

    small = models.ImageField(upload_to="small/",blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/",blank=True)

    if image:
        Resizier(image)
    else:
        small = image
        Resizier(image)
```

my fields.py

```
from PIL import Image as img
import math

image = {}
class Resizier(image):


    def save(self , force_insert=False,force_update=False):
        super (Picture,self).save(force_insert,force_update)

        pw = self.image.width
        ph = self.image.height
        mw = 400
        mh = 400

        if (pw > mw) or (ph > mh):
            filename = str(self.image.path)
            imageObj = img.open(filename)
            ratio = 1

            if ( pw > mw):
                ratio = mw / float(pw)
                pw = mw
                ph = int(math.floor(float(ph)* ratio))
            if ( ph > mh):
                ratio = ratio * ( mh /float(ph))
                ph = mh 
                pw = int(math.floor(float(ph)* ratio))

            imageObj = imageObj.resize((pw,ph),img.ANTIALIAS)
            imageObj.save(filename)
```

Error

```
    from pet.fields import Resizier
  File "C:\o\17\mysite\pet\fields.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Resizier(image):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

Comment: Please, instead of all the code you posted, just post the complete error `python` shows (the _stack trace_, we need to see it) and the function that contains the erroneous code, according to the file:line reported

Comment: Okay Posted at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
from PIL import Image as img
import math

image = {}
class Resizier(image): # you are inheriting from `image`, which is a dict,
                       # you probably want `Picture` here.
```

However you have some other problems as well. Might I suggest instead of trying to re-invent the wheel, use something already available. Here is a [list of packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/photos/) that provide this functionality.

Comment: What kind of problems , can you explain bit further please ?

Comment: Burhan Khalid Do you mean problem like if my resize function will scale?